# On button click send Ajax call and get value from aspx.cs(code behind) to aspx page and display it in input field in the same page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am new to `AJAX` and have stuck in a problem, I want to send **AJAX CALL** on button click, while button clicking the value of input field is sent to `aspx.cs` (code behind) page and response should be get and I try to show that response to that same input field but it's not working.

**ASPX CODE:**

```
<input type="text" class="wpcf7-text" id="d_id" name="d_id" runat="server"> // this id is sent to the Read_Driver_Account funtion and on response it is sending the driver cell number which i want to display in the driver cell number imput field
<input class="wpcf7-text" id="driver_cell" name="driver_cell" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="btnn1" OnClick="Read_Driver_Account" runat="server"  Text="Get"/>
<script>
$("btnn1").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Udate_Driver_Account/",   //Udate_Driver_Account.aspx file is placed in VisualStudio/Websites/Fp/Udate_Driver_Account.aspx, where Fp is name of my website.
            data: {
                id: $(this).val(), 
                driver_cell: $("#drivercel").val()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert('ok');
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

**ASPX.CS CODE:**

```
public string drivercel;

protected void Read_Driver_Account(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var alldata = d_id.Value;
string driveradres = tokens[7];
string drivercel = tokens[8];  // i want to set this value to the input field id="driver_cell"
}
```

Note: tokens[8] is a value coming from a live database it's not a static value;
Also i want to set more than one values to more than one input fields.

Comment: You could work with `Web API`, `WebMethods` or `Postback`. Take a look [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) for `WebMethods` (which aren't state of the art anymore).

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932623/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-web-api-over-web-method-in-asp-net) is also an interesting source

Answer (score 0):

The `JQuery` selector you used should be `$("#btnn1")` instead of `$("btnn1")`. Then the ajax url should be `/pageName/webMethod` like `/Udate_Driver_Account.aspx/Read_Driver_Account`.

And use `JSON.stringify` to send the data as `data: JSON.stringify({ id: $(this).val(), driver_cell: $("#drivercel").val() })`.

Add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` to send the data as json and `dataType: "json"` to get the response data as json.

```
<input class="wpcf7-text" id="driver_cell" name="driver_cell" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="btnn1" OnClick="Read_Driver_Account" runat="server"  Text="Get"/>
<script>
$("#btnn1").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Udate_Driver_Account.aspx/Read_Driver_Account",   //Udate_Driver_Account.aspx file is placed in VisualStudio/Websites/Fp/Udate_Driver_Account.aspx, where Fp is name of my website.
            data: JSON.stringify({
                id: $(this).val(), 
                driver_cell: $("#drivercel").val()
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                // $("#drivercel").val(result.d);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Then mark your method with `WebMethod` attribute and make it as `public static` with parameter name same as the data json above.

```
public string drivercel;

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string Read_Driver_Account(string id, string driver_cell)
{
  string drivercel = tokens[8];  // i want to set this value to the input field id="driver_cell"
  return drivercel;
}
```

**Note**: As you used the `asp:Button` id directly in `JQuery` selector, you should add `ClientIDMode="Static"` property to the button as below to use the same id in client side (OR add the same in `Page` directive). Otherwise, the button will have different dynamic id in client side and the JQuery click event won't get fired.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnn1" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="Read_Driver_Account" runat="server"  Text="Get"/>
```

Comment: There's one more thing i want to add which i havent added before, which is i am also sending a variable value while calling a function from button click. I have updated the question code. please review.